# Disable click event when a user provides feedback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and trying to find a way to disable the click events for two divs when a user provides feedback with javascript. Any assistance provided would be grateful. How might I do that with the below code:

```
var SubmitRating = React.createClass({

  FEEDBACK_PHASE: 1,  // - user agrees to give feedback and is yet to give
  THANKS_PHASE: 2,    // - user gave feedback

  getInitialState: function () {
      return {
          "phase": this.FEEDBACK_PHASE
      }
  },

  setPhase: function(phase) {
      this.setState({
          "phase": phase
      });
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
      if(nextProps.active) {
          this.setPhase(this.FEEDBACK_PHASE);
      }
  },

  submitRating: function(rating) {
      var currentVideo = this.props.currentVideoData;

      this.setPhase(this.THANKS_PHASE);
      this.props.submitDone();
      //TODO : need to add more parameters which will be sent to rating app
      ajaxPost("/answer_rating", {"documentID": currentVideo.talk_id,
                                "startTime": currentVideo.start_time_sec,
                                "endTime": currentVideo.stop_time_sec,
                                "userRanking": rating,
                                "hashCode": currentVideo.metadata.hash,
                                "questionText": currentVideo.metadata.question }, function(response){
          console.log(response);
      });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.active ? "feedback-options-container" : "hidden"}>
        <div className={this.state.phase == this.FEEDBACK_PHASE ? "feedback-options" : "hidden"} >
            <div className="option-relevant" onClick={this.submitRating.bind(this, 10)}> This video answered correctly </div>
            <div className="option-irrelevant" onClick={this.submitRating.bind(this, 1)}> This video did not answer properly </div>
        </div>
        <div className={this.state.phase == this.THANKS_PHASE ? "feedback-reply" : "hidden"}> <h4> Thanks for your feedback </h4> </div>
      </div>
    )
  },

});
```

Comment: you have quite a few questions which have not been marked as answered. Please do mark them (if they solved the question) so that other can also learn from it. [Here is how you mark as answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, you want to trigger a re-render by changing the state in order the change the component. Just like you are already doing with the classes, use inline conditions to change the output of the markup.

```
// change
onClick={this.submitRating.bind(this, 10)}
// to
onClick={this.state.someCondition ? this.submitRating.bind(this, 10) : null}
```

Once your click event (and ajax?) stuff finishes, simply use `this.setState` to trigger a re-render, just like you are already doing with the classes.

edit:

Assuming you want the click listeners to disable with the `phase` change, you can use:

```
onClick={this.state.phase == this.FEEDBACK_PHASE ? this.submitRating.bind(this, 10) : null}
```

Comment: Would it not be

onClick={this.state.phase == this.FEEDBACK_PHASE ? this.submitRating.bind(this, 10) : null}

Comment: @kirdua: Correct, I was thinking backwards. Will edit

Comment: @kirdua: If this worked then please mark this as the correct answer to close it. Thanks